# ExecuteSqlCommand with DbContext

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

We are using repository and unit of work patterns for our application

I have the below method to execute stored proc:

```
 /*** Execute stored procedure ***/
        public virtual void ExecuteProcedure(String procedureCommand, params SqlParameter[] sqlParams)
        {
            Ctxt.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(procedureCommand, sqlParams);
        }
```

My client repository will invoke the method as below:

```
 //Check lock conditions for site part vrsm
        public bool CanLock(int spvId)
        {
            SqlParameter output = new SqlParameter("editMode", SqlDbType.Bit);
            output.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("spvId", SqlDbType.Int);
        parameter.Value = spvId;

        ExecuteProcedure("exec [dbo].[prc_SitePartVrsn_CanLock] {0}, @editMode = {1} output", parameter, output);

        return Convert.ToBoolean(output.Value);
    }
```

However line `ExecuteProcedure` is failing with

> "Incorrect syntax near 0"

I don't have any other information in Innerexception or no clue from stack trace.
The procedure is working fine when I execute it in database.

Can somebody advise what is the problem ???

Comment: Profile the sql and you will see what is actually executed in the DB so you can fix your syntax.

Comment: Where are you formating the string. like where are you assigning the values to {0} and {1}. copy the final string procedure here which is recieved in execute stored procedure.

Comment: @QasimJavaidKhan. String formatting is not relevant, this is using [`ExecuteSqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456(v=vs.103).aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need much of a change, it is only a syntax issue:

```
ExecuteProcedure("exec prc_SitePartVrsn_CanLock @spvId, @editMode OUTPUT", parameter, output);
```

And you can either use `[dbo].[prc_SitePartVrsn_CanLock]` or `prc_SitePartVrsn_CanLock`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
ExecuteProcedure("exec [dbo].[prc_SitePartVrsn_CanLock] @spvId, @editMode", parameter, output);
```